# Is there a quicker way than having a for loop in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a quicker way than using a for loop in a for loop to replace the variables in column a in one table with the variables in column b in another table.

```
for x in range(len(a["a"])):
    for y in range(len(b["a"])):
        if a["a"][x] == b["a"][y]:
            a["a"] = out['a'].replace([a["a"][x]],b["b"][y]])
```

This currently works but is super slow, is there anyway to do the same thing but make it faster?

Sample Data:

```html
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 'h', 'i']}) 

b = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'], 'b': ['alpha', 'alpha', 'alpha', 'beta', 'beta', 'charlie' 'charlie']})
```

Basically I am trying to replace the value in a["a"] with the values in b["b"] if a["a"] == b["a"]

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632). Also [ask].

Comment: I apologize the data I work with is confidential, and I struggle with making a table on here its always iffy when I try to make it and ruins my entire question

Comment: @AhmedTawakol The easiest way to do that is to do `df.to_dict()`, which does not produce a table, but does produce something you can put inside a call to `pd.DataFrame()`. That means that people can just copy/paste the code into their own editor.

Comment: added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the pandas `where` function because your two dataframes have different numbers of elements. But the code below will work (I renamed your dataframes df1 and df2 for clarity)

```
df1['a'].loc[df1['a'].isin(df2['a'])] = df2['b']
```

which for your sample data results in

```
         a
0    alpha
1    alpha
2    alpha
3     beta
4     beta
5  charlie
6  charlie
7        h
8        i
```

Comment: I got an error saying "Can only compare identically labeled data frame objects"

Comment: I added some sample data apologies

Comment: Answer code edited on the basis of the sample data you provided.